# Extract data from table by merging rows

Tags: plsql

I have a table with data as below

```
|Transaction Seq|Sub Seq|Item No|Location Code|Quantity|Moved|

|54321          |1      |001    |AUXB1        |500     | O   | 

|54321          |2      |001    |PBXB1        |500     | I   |
```

Which basically says 500 boxes of item 001 has moved from location AUXB1 to PBXB1. Moved basically says whether the item is moved In or Out. Now I have to export the data as below

```
54321|001|500|AUXB1|PBXB1
```

Now the complexity arises when the item from one location has moved to 2 different location or the other way around as well.

```
|Transaction Seq|Sub Seq|Item No|Location Code|Quantity|Moved

|54321          |1      |001    |AUXB1        |500     | O

|54321          |2      |001    |PBXB1        |300     | I

|54321          |3      |001    |BAXB1        |200     | I
```

Now the extract has to contain, two lines as below

```
54321|001|300|AUXB1|PBXB1  
54321|001|200|AUXB1|BAXB1
```

For below case

```
|Transaction Seq|Sub Seq|Item No|Location Code|Quantity|Moved

|54321          |1      |001    |AUXB1        |500     | I

|54321          |2      |001    |PBXB1        |300     | O

|54321          |3      |001    |BAXB1        |200     | O
```

The extract has to be as below

```
54321|001|300|PBXB1|AUXB1

54321|001|200|BAXB1|AUXB1
```

Please let me know how this can be achieved.

Comment: If there were two moves of the same item, presumably the transaction seq would be different for those moves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your logic correctly, all you need is an inner join between the "in" rows and the "out" rows in your table:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 54321 transaction_seq, 1 sub_seq, '001' item_no, 'AUXB1' location_code, 500 quantity, 'O' moved FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 54321 transaction_seq, 2 sub_seq, '001' item_no, 'PBXB1' location_code, 500 quantity, 'I' moved FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 54322 transaction_seq, 1 sub_seq, '001' item_no, 'AUXB1' location_code, 500 quantity, 'O' moved FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 54322 transaction_seq, 2 sub_seq, '001' item_no, 'PBXB1' location_code, 300 quantity, 'I' moved FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 54322 transaction_seq, 3 sub_seq, '001' item_no, 'BAXB1' location_code, 200 quantity, 'I' moved FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 54323 transaction_seq, 1 sub_seq, '001' item_no, 'AUXB1' location_code, 500 quantity, 'I' moved FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 54323 transaction_seq, 2 sub_seq, '001' item_no, 'PBXB1' location_code, 300 quantity, 'O' moved FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 54323 transaction_seq, 3 sub_seq, '001' item_no, 'BAXB1' location_code, 200 quantity, 'O' moved FROM dual)
SELECT out_rows.transaction_seq,
       out_rows.item_no,
       least(out_rows.quantity, in_rows.quantity) quantity,
       out_rows.location_code moved_from,
       in_rows.location_code moved_to
FROM   your_table out_rows
       INNER JOIN your_table in_rows ON out_rows.transaction_seq = in_rows.transaction_seq
                                        AND out_rows.item_no = in_rows.item_no
                                        AND out_rows.moved = 'O'
                                        AND in_rows.moved = 'I';


TRANSACTION_SEQ ITEM_NO   QUANTITY MOVED_FROM MOVED_TO
--------------- ------- ---------- ---------- --------
          54321 001            500 AUXB1      PBXB1
          54322 001            300 AUXB1      PBXB1
          54322 001            200 AUXB1      BAXB1
          54323 001            200 BAXB1      AUXB1
          54323 001            300 PBXB1      AUXB1
```

I've assumed you don't need to do any checks that the quantities match, and that each transaction_seq covers one move (i.e. one "out" location to one or multiple "in" locations, or one "in" location to one or multiple "out" locations). If you could have multiple "out" locations moving the same item to multiple "in" locations within a single transaction_seq, this solution won't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot @boneist for your response this worked. As you have mentioned this worked for the cases where either In or Out location is 1 . There are few records where the items are moved from multiple "Out" locations to multiple "in" Locations. Request you to help on how to handle this scenario as well.

Comment: You'd have to raise a new question and provide more data on the scenario and what you'd expect to see. For example, say there were 3 "out" rows and 4 "in" rows within a transaction_seq, all different locations; which "out" rows match to which "in" rows, and why? What would the quantities need to show, etc.